# Thread safety for synchronized HashMap's clear() method

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, synchronization

I have a HashMap consisting of unique int keys (autoboxing to Integer) and double[] values. Size is ~100.
I'm only using .put() & .get() methods.
I need to regularly "reset" the HashMap and repopulate it with new key/values pairs. I do that using a .clear(), and .put() in a loop to repopulate (I could also simply create a new HashMap instead).

In a single-threaded environment, no issue at all.

In a multi-threaded environment, I can use a SynchronizedMap, or a ConcurrentHashMap, both will take care of my put() & get() thread safety.

What about the .clear() method ? How to ensure it's thread-safe ? Should I simply use a synchronized block ?

Also, how would creating a new HashMap instead have an impact on thread safety in this context ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [clear method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.Segment.clear%28%29) have the locking management as well.

```
  void  clear() {
577             if (count != 0) {
578                 lock();
579                 try {
580                     HashEntry<K,V>[] tab = table;
581                     for (int i = 0; i < tab.length ; i++)
582                         tab[i] = null;
583                     ++modCount;
584                     count = 0; // write-volatile
585                 } finally {
586                     unlock();
587                 }
588             }
589         }
590     }
```